# Using REACT to read values from elements using Id (getElementsById("myField"))

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid

**Edited original post:**
Skipping all the back story and why it is so, I have an auto generated HTML form with elements that have a consistent Id, but not Name attributes.
Eg:

```
<textarea name="something_random_12345677890_always_changes" rows="10" cols="20" maxlength="1000" id="new_myField">
    Contents of the text area here
</textarea>
```

I'd ideally use something like this in REACT if only document.getElementBy**Id**("new_myField") was available, but that always returns a NULL and does not find the element.

```
    const myInputField = document.getElementById("new_myField");
```

Is there a way to reference my element by Id?

I've seen some other posts relating to this issue including using "useEffect" but their scenario is slightly different and I'm too novice to work out how to fit it into my scenario.

Here's the full code as how I understood it from #RedFlash. But maybe I've implemented it incorrectly?

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  function Getnew_myField() {
    useEffect(() => {
      const ddf_formconfigurationjson = document.getElementById('new_myField');
      if (ddf_formconfigurationjson[0]?.value) {
        alert("new_myField: " + ddf_formconfigurationjson[0].value);
      } else {
        alert("new_myField does not exist");
      }
    }, [])
  }


  function ConfigReady(event) {
    Getnew_myField();
    
    //This always returns null
    //const new_myField = document.getElementById("new_myField");
    //if (new_myField[0]?.value) {
    //  alert("new_myField: " + new_myField[0].value);
    //} else {
    //  alert("new_myField does not exist");
    //}
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <textarea name="something_random_12345677890_always_changes"
          rows="10"
          cols="20"
          maxlength="1000"
          id='new_myField'>
          Contents of the text area here
        </textarea>

        <input
          name="ConfigReady"
          id="ConfigReady"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={ConfigReady}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );


}

export default App;
```

It's throwing an error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've eventually solved it in a different way. I'm using JQuery to access the DOM.

To add JQuery functionality to the app I installed it first:

```
npm install jquery
```

Then import it:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Finally, able to use it to reference elements this way:

```
const myVar = $('#new_myField').val();
```

The above "new_myField" is the element ID.

But just to complicate things... I tried using "document.getElementById(...)" in my code again just to confirm and suddenly it's working fine. The whole sample code in my problem is functioning now. I can only assume that installing the JQuery package did something?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use React I guess you should try the `useEffect()` and `useRef()` hooks.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function GetElement() {
    const yourRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        const inputField = yourRef.current
    },[])
    return(
        <main>
           <textarea name="something_random_12345677890_always_changes" 
                    rows="10" 
                    cols="20" 
                    maxlength="1000" 
                    ref={yourRef}>
                    Contents of the text area here
            </textarea>
        </main>
    )
}
```

If you don't want to use the `useRef` hook, you can always get it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect} from 'react';

export default function GetElement() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const inputField = document.getElementById('new_myField');
    },[])
    return(
        <main>
           <textarea name="something_random_12345677890_always_changes" 
                    rows="10" 
                    cols="20" 
                    maxlength="1000" 
                    id='new_myField'>
                    Contents of the text area here
            </textarea>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Note that we always passing an empty array to `useEffect()` hook.

There are also probably a lot more ways, but I hope this will help you.

Comment: thankyou. I tried it but now I'm getting an error un using useEffect(). Did I implement it wrong? I've updated the original post.

**Error:** 
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, somehow i miss the comment. Check where u calling the hook. They are also 3 rules of hooks, i recommend you to check them. In the certain example i export this function to the app.js/jsx(the main) that renders. Check if you import it correctly from the right directory etc.. Also be sure you import the hook outside the return() of the function and also inside the function you are going to export.  Again i will recommend you to check the 3 rules of hooks in react it will help you a lot, even for further use of hooks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update with working example:**

```js
const myInputField = document.getElementById("new_myField");
console.log(myInputField.value)
```

```html
<textarea name="something_random_12345677890_always_changes" rows="10" cols="20" maxlength="1000" id="new_myField">
    Contents of the text area here
</textarea>
```

**Explanation:**

You have a typo in getElement**s**ById. It should be

```
 const myInputField = document.getElementById("new_myField");
```

without the s after Element, because Ids have to be unique and only used for a single element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Patrick... First I kicked myself very hard for missing that s the whole time. Then I tried it out and even though the error is no longer thrown, it's still returning null. "getElementById" is still a problem.

Comment: @CheeseNWine Your <textarea> with the correctly spelled getElementById works perfectly fine. When are you accessing the element? Before or after the DOM is loaded? Can you provide your React code?

Comment: I've updated the original post with the complete code. Although no error is raised from it, I'm still not receiving anything from the getElementById.

Comment: I am only able to comment my own answers until I have enough rep, so I do it here: Installing JQuery only for this purpose is a bit overkill. The code in your edited answer has an error in it, you are not using useEffect the right way. I could add another answer, but the answer of RedFlash has the correct code already in it. WIth the correct React code you won't need JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20734788/patrick) is correct, the issue here is a typo.

However, if you are using React, it's commonplace to use the `useRef` hook to store elements.

**Example:**

```
function MyComponent() {
   const myElementRef = useRef()

   return <div ref={myElementRef}></div>
}
```

Then to access it's value (the element), you would use the following syntax:

```
const myElement = myElementRef.current
```

Note that it can and will default to a value of `undefined` before assigning the element upon first render, so be sure to check for that if necessary.

For more info, check out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components).

PS, this is only revelant for elements that are within your React app.
If the element is outside of it, you would need to use the standard document functions.